# create a variable that will store an integer number of all bars on the chart

Tags: pine-script

create a variable containing

```
highest(high, value)
```

at the same time, so that the variable "value" has a number that is equal to all the bars on the chart
if there are 5931 bars on the chart, then the value variable must contain the number 5931

i tried to do so

```
int vival = na
val = bar_index
val_string = tostring(bar_index)
val_int = tonumber(val_string)
ival = round(val_int)
vival := ival


ath = highest(high, integer)
```

buy i get error

```
invalid value of the "lenght" argument (0.0)
in the "highest" function. It must be > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this problem with this code

```
value = barssince(barstate.isfirst)
x = highest(high, int(max(1, nz(barssince(cond)) + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster, and more accurate.

```
//@version=4
study("ATH", overlay = true)

var float ath = 0

if high > ath
    ath := high

if barstate.islast
    line.new(time, ath, time+1, ath, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.yellow)
```

Comment: Thank you. i am new to pine script and your code is really more convenient and better